# Howto create azure postgres server with admin-password in keyvault?

Tags: postgresql, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

To make parameters using key vaults available for my azure webapp I've executed the following

```
        identity=`az webapp identity assign \
          --name $(appName) \
          --resource-group $(appResourceGroupName) \
          --query principalId -o tsv`

        az keyvault set-policy \
          --name $(keyVaultName) \
          --secret-permissions get \
          --object-id $identity
```

Now I want to create an azure postgres server taking admin-password from a key vault:

```
                az postgres server create \
                --location $(location) \
                --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) \
                --name $(PostgresServerName) \
                --admin-user $(AdminUserName) \
                --admin-password '$(AdminPassWord)' \
                --sku-name $(pgSkuName)
```

If the value of my AdminPassWord is here something like

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://<myKv>.vault.azure.net/secrets/AdminPassWord/)
```

I need the single quotes (like above) to get the postgres server created. But does this mean that the password will be the whole string `'@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://<myKv>.vault.azure.net/secrets/AdminPassWord/)'` instead of the secret stored in `<myKv>` ?

When running my pipeline without the quotes  (i.e. just `--admin-password $(AdminPassWord) \`) I got the error message `syntax error near unexpected token ('`. I thought that it could be consequence of the fact that I have't set the policy `--secret-permissions get` for the resource postgres server. But how can I set it before creating the postgres server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expresssion `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://<myKv>.vault.azure.net/secrets/AdminPassWord/)`  is used to access the keyvault secret value in azure web app, when you configure it with the first two commands, the managed identity of the web app will be able to access the keyvault secret.

But if you want to create an azure postgres server with the password, you need to obtain the secret value firstly and use it rather than use the expression.

For Azure CLI, you could use [`az keyvault secret show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_secret_show), then pass the secret to the parameter `--admin-password` in `az postgres server create`.

```
az keyvault secret show [--id]
                        [--name]
                        [--query-examples]
                        [--subscription]
                        [--vault-name]
                        [--version]
```